# setState of an object within an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given my state looks like so:

```
cart: [
  { id: 1, name: 'apple', price: 100, quantity: 1 }
]
```

How do I `setState` of that specific object's `quantity` property ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `indexOf` the item in the cart which you want to update, and update the `cart` with everything up to that item, your updated item, and the rest of the items.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cart: [
      { id: 1, name: "apple", price: 100, quantity: 1 },
      { id: 2, name: "orange", price: 50, quantity: 10 },
      { id: 3, name: "banana", price: 20, quantity: 100 }
    ]
  };

  increaseQuantity = item => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      const { cart } = previousState;
      const itemIndex = cart.indexOf(item);

      return {
        cart: [
          ...cart.slice(0, itemIndex),
          { ...cart[itemIndex], quantity: cart[itemIndex].quantity + 1 },
          ...cart.slice(itemIndex + 1)
        ]
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.cart.map(item => (
          <div key={item.id} onClick={() => this.increaseQuantity(item)}>
            {item.name} {item.quantity}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Any reason you do `{cart}` here?

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Just in case the updates to `quantity` comes in very frequently, there could be race conditions where the state is not updated properly unless the `cart` is taken from the previous state in the `setState` callback.

Comment: @Tholle That can never happen from a single event handler because of how React batches setState calls during an event. That said, I always encourage the use of functional setState when the new state depends on the previous one. Anyway, In my comment though, I was wondering why you are destructuring `cart` from `previousState` rather than using it directly.

Comment: @Chris You're right, that's very true. I didn't give it much more thought except for the "new state depends on the previous one" rule of thumb you just mentioned. I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, sorry. I just didn't want to write `previousState.cart` multiple times.

Comment: Functional setState rules ;) No, I was just wondering if you did it to shorten your code or for other reasons. You answered my question now though.

Comment: just to add a quick note here, its not recommended to have an inline lambda in the render as that creates a new function each render cycle which isn't performant and can cause additional re renders on child elements. its best to have these functions on the class, or child components. if you stick with the inline function approach at least use `.bind` instead of `() => {}` as bind is about twice as performant. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can update your cart as

```
updateCart(id, itemAttributes) {
  var index = this.state.cart.findIndex(x=> x.id === id);
  if (index === -1)
    // handle error
  else
    this.setState({
      cart: [
         ...this.state.cart.slice(0, index),
         Object.assign({}, this.state.cart[index], itemAttributes),
         ...this.state.cart.slice(index+1)
      ]
    });
}
```

then call your updateCart function with id of your cart item as

```
this.updateCart(1, {quantity: 2});
```

Comment: This is nice, but why use spread in two places, but `Object.assign` in the other? Wouldn't it be better to do spread on all three?

Comment: @Chris spread will also work here. Object.assign can mutate the original object which is sometimes useful. spread cannot.

Answer (score 2):

```
 this.setState(prev => ({
   cart: [{ ...prev.cart[0], quantity: 10, }].concat(prev.cart.slice(1))
 }));
```

Copy the array and replace the object you wanna change with a copied version. If you do that often you may use some utilities:

```
const replace = index, replacer) => arr =>
   arr.map((el, i) => i === index ? replacer(el) : el);
const key = (k, replacer)  => state => ({...state, [k]: replacer(state[k]) });
```

Usable as:

```
this.setState(key(
   "cart", 
   replace(
     0, 
     key("quantity", () => 10)
   )
));
```